# Mysql compare average results with current result in a single query

Tags: mysql

I am wondering if it's possible to run a single query that tells me the following:

> ***Get the names of any applications that have (currently executing) jobs exceeding the average historical runtime***

**Table 1: Job History**

- Job start time
- Job end time
- Job status (success, failure, executing, etc.)
- Application ID that triggered job

**Table 2: Applications**

- ID
- Name

It seemed like a simple question to answer, but creating a mysql query has proven to be a rather involved (albeit intriguing) challenge...

The query needs to grab the jobs where **`satus = executing`**, use the **`application.id`** to look for other jobs that have a matching **`application.id`** and **`status = success`**, average the **(`end_time` - `start_time`)**, and then compare the **`average time`** with the **(`current_time` - `start_time`)** of the currently executing jobs.  Finally, it must use the application ID from any jobs that fail this test to grab the **`application.name`** from the application table.  Is that even possible to do in a single query?

For the sake of this question, let's assume **`current_time`** is passed in as an argument.

I made an attempt at a triple nested query, but I'm getting the following error, and I don't know why.  I've spent a few hours trying to get this to work, but I'm already in over my head here:

`ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'jh.start_time' in 'having clause'`

This is my attempt:

```
SELECT name FROM application
WHERE application.id IN (
    SELECT application_id 
    FROM job_history AS jh
    WHERE application_id IN (
        SELECT application_id 
        FROM job_history
        WHERE status='EXECUTION' )
    AND jh.status='SUCCESS'
    HAVING (avg(jh.end_time - jh.start_time)) < (current_time - jh.start_time)
    );
```

*Edit: As suggested, here is some sample data.*

**Table 1**

```
+--------+------------+------------+----------+----------------+
| job_id |   status   | start_time | end_time | application_id |
+--------+------------+------------+----------+----------------+
| job1   | successful |        100 |      200 | app1           |
| job2   | failed     |        150 |      350 | app2           |
| job3   | successful |        200 |      400 | app1           |
| job4   | execution  |        500 |        0 | app1           |
| job5   | successful |        600 |      800 | app3           |
+--------+------------+------------+----------+----------------+
```

**Table 2**

```
+------+------------------+
|  id  |       name       |
+------+------------------+
| app1 | Team Green's app |
| app2 | Team Blue's app  |
| app3 | Team Red's app   |
+------+------------------+
```

I would like to grab **job4**, use the `application_id` to find **job1** and **job3**.  Then take the average run time of **job1** and **job3** and compare it against the current runtime of **job4**.  If the current runtime is greater than the average runtime, then I would like to report the application name: **Team Green's app**.

Comment: You might have more success if you provide sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, here's one option using a `join`.  From here it's easy to adjust the `where` criteria to your needs:

```
select distinct a.name
from applications a 
    join jobhistory jh on a.id = jh.applicationid
    join (
      select applicationid, avg(endtime - starttime) avgtime
      from jobhistory
      where status = 'success'
      group by applicationid
    ) t on a.id = t.applicationid
where jh.status = 'execution' and 
  @current_time - jh.starttime > t.avgtime
```

Comment: Nice!  I like where this is going, but won't this only return results with statuses of 'success'?  Or in this case an empy set, because later we look for status = 'execution'.

Comment: @EthanStrider -- per your comment (`that have a matching application.id and status = success`), that's what the `join` and the subquery are accomplishing.  It returns the `avg` time so you can compare it with those that are still executing in the outer main `where` criteria.  Have you tried this yet, is it returning the incorrect results?

Comment: The jobs that are actively executing are stored in the same table as jobs that have finished.  So, I need to grab the active jobs first, then use the application_id to identify historical jobs that have finished successfully.  Then take the average time of the historical jobs to finish running and go *back* to the active jobs and compare the average run time with the current run time.  I'll update my description above with some sample data.

Comment: I meant to say this earlier, but I did try this, and it is returning an empty set.  Even if I remove the last line (`and @current_time - jh.starttime > t.avgtime`) it still returns an empty set.

Comment: @EthanStrider -- SQL Fiddle is unfortunately not working correctly now.  I was able to find this other online sql editor, plugged in your sample data with my sample query and it returns `Team Green`: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_sql_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMYUluWUJJM2lwbVk

Comment: Thanks for putting so much effort into your answer!  I got it working.  My issue was the status should be `executing` instead of `execution`.  It works perfectly, and it is beautiful!